# Primary Key on a temp-table messes up the results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a "Why does this happen??? - Question"

I have the following script:

```
DECLARE @sql_stmt nvarchar(max)

SET @sql_stmt = '
   select top 100000 id as id
   from  dat.sev_sales_event
   order by id
'

DECLARE @preResult TABLE ( sales_event_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @preResult(sales_event_id)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_stmt

SELECT * FROM @preResult
```

If I run this script, results may vary each time it's executed

By simply removing **"PRIMARY KEY"** from the temporary-table, results stay stable

Can someone tell me the theory to this behaviour?

Kind regards
Jürgen

Comment: Why do need dynamic SQL (`sp_executesql`) for this? What happens when you directly use a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT TOP...`?

Comment: Using the primary key: does it change without inserting rows or rather after inserting/updating/deleting rows?

Comment: What dou you mean by saying _vary_, different number of rows returned or different order of rows? Try to add `order by sales_event_id` to last statement. Is it still different after?

Comment: This is only a short version of the real script => which is built dynamically out of various expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the result set is different or just in a different order?

Adding a primary key to the temporary table should result in the contents of the table being ordered numerically ascending, and so appear 'stable'. Removing this will remove the inherent ordering.

Comment: Ohh boy, yeah, that's the problem, didn't think the easy way :-)

Comment: Mmmm, so it is more stabe having the index on the table? The question appeared to be the other way round ;)

Answer (score 4):

## The order of data in a database has no meaning.

If you want your results to be ordered then you **must** specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

This is irrespective of having a PRIMARY key or not.

The following scripts illustrate the issue nicely

- [Expecting order without ORDER BY (1).sql - gvee.co.uk](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20%281%29.sql)
- [Expecting order without ORDER BY (2).sql - gvee.co.uk](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20%282%29.sql)
- [Expecting order without ORDER BY (3).sql - gvee.co.uk](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20%283%29.sql)

Comment: The weired to me was, that the data is inserted orderd, when not defining the column as Primary Key - it seems in this case it takes the order of the statement

Comment: @J.Starkl Even though it might work, the behaviour is not guaranteed. When no `ORDER BY` is defined, the order is undefined. Also see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx).